Issue in Fetching Data in Power App TextInput Fields using Power Automate
I have made a power automate flow to fetch a particular row from google sheet, in Power App.
In the app, when I will type a primary key value and press the search button, the textinput fields should display the data from the google sheet. For that I have written a code for the search button. I have attached the code below:
`    // Trigger the flow and store the response
Set(
response,
DM_Sheet_Search.Run(TextInput1.Text) //DM_Sheet_Search is the flow name
);
// Debugging: Display the entire response using JSON
Notify("Response received: " & JSON(response, JSONFormat.Compact), NotificationType.Information);

// Check if response contains expected fields and update text input fields
If(
!IsError(response),
// Assuming response is an object with fields
If(
    !IsBlank(response.review),
    UpdateContext({ textInput1_1Value: response.review })
);
If(
    !IsBlank(response.msshrutireview),
    UpdateContext({ textInput1_2Value: response.msshrutireview})
);
If(
    !IsBlank(response.mrgirishreview),
    UpdateContext({ textInput1_3Value: response.mrgirishreview})  //a,b,c are the column names of the google sheet
)
);

// Ensure text input fields are updated with variable values
TextInput1_1.Text = textInput1_1Value;
TextInput1_2.Text = textInput1_2Value;
TextInput1_3.Text = textInput1_3Value;`

The data is being fetched but not displayed on the respective textinput fields.[ScreenShot of PowerApp and Automate Flow](https://i.sstatic.net/fMNKuw6t.jpg)
Tried fetching and displaying data on a text input field on a Power App, using Automate Flow.
I expected the text input fields to display the fetched data from the google sheet, so that I can update/delete the data fields.
Output Body Of Get Rows in Power Automate:

 {
  "@odata.context": "https://googledrive-ci.azconn-ci- 
  001.p.azurewebsites.net/$metadata#datasets('1nySnd4- 
  PKJfSIoOnXe31D_M- 
  wiZeIlKWPVOTW8NUxmg')/tables('495289366')/items",
  value": [
 {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "61a29650d840475b877250f1dbc0c561",
  "SR_No": "1",
  "Sheet_Name": "PROVIDED SERVICES TO INDUSTRY",
  "Review": "Similar Webite To Beneficiation",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "In Progress",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "61a29650d840475b877250f1dbc0c561,2"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "447184d5102a49ffa12ab4c3526d57ea",
  "SR_No": "2",
  "Sheet_Name": "GSI WEBSITE SERVICES",
  "Review": "Website All Services and Keywords Mention",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "447184d5102a49ffa12ab4c3526d57ea,3"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "7e54ca5d677349369d8e5e9c354b59ba",
  "SR_No": "3",
  "Sheet_Name": "OFFICE EMPLOYEE SHEET",
  "Review": "All Office Employees Data",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "7e54ca5d677349369d8e5e9c354b59ba,4"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "1c6f1a261e124d89abc9acd6c7b20951",
  "SR_No": "4",
  "Sheet_Name": "OFFICE FINAL ADDRESS",
  "Review": "Final Company Address",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "1c6f1a261e124d89abc9acd6c7b20951,5"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "7ae7f50e50df47fb8a60a20e70d3d6da",
  "SR_No": "5",
  "Sheet_Name": "BUGS LIST",
  "Review": "Bugs list on Gsinfotechvis",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "7ae7f50e50df47fb8a60a20e70d3d6da,6"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "a61510feccf8479fa79ce1fb44407008",
  "SR_No": "6",
  "Sheet_Name": "EMAIL CAMPAIGN REPORT",
  "Review": "Email Campaign Analysis",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "a61510feccf8479fa79ce1fb44407008,7"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "60abe0c193c142499cb0507793631cd8",
  "SR_No": "7",
  "Sheet_Name": "TELEGRAM GROUP LINK",
  "Review": "Telegram Group Links",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "60abe0c193c142499cb0507793631cd8,8"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "d2338bd118414beb907d93a50f22c2e3",
  "SR_No": "8",
  "Sheet_Name": "2024 FESTIVAL CALENDAR",
  "Review": "In 2024 festival Calendar",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "d2338bd118414beb907d93a50f22c2e3,9"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "66a657650a9e43cb96c66782ac5b7324",
  "SR_No": "9",
  "Sheet_Name": "GSI BACKLINK APPROCH",
  "Review": "Similar Webite To Beneficiation",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "66a657650a9e43cb96c66782ac5b7324,10"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "b30a2027371a4837b38cd6897dc69b79",
  "SR_No": "10",
  "Sheet_Name": "FACEBOOK ADD SET",
  "Review": "Understand Facebook Add Set",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "In Progress",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "b30a2027371a4837b38cd6897dc69b79,11"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "46923e7b9bfe40459a8d8fd6ebae68a5",
  "SR_No": "11",
  "Sheet_Name": "BLOG TRACKING SHEET",
  "Review": "Easy To Analysis Blog",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "46923e7b9bfe40459a8d8fd6ebae68a5,12"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "ca30746cef99401aaa3c2e529f9f7aa6",
  "SR_No": "12",
  "Sheet_Name": "WEB CRAFFING FOUNDED",
  "Review": "Website Data Craffing",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "ca30746cef99401aaa3c2e529f9f7aa6,13"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "521f4811295a49a7a290747bc6115828",
  "SR_No": "13",
  "Sheet_Name": "SBM",
  "Review": "Backlinks",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "In Progress",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "521f4811295a49a7a290747bc6115828,14"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "42f21cbfce504964928a005da351ca02",
  "SR_No": "14",
  "Sheet_Name": "ARTICLE",
  "Review": "Backlinks",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "42f21cbfce504964928a005da351ca02,15"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "6020b21a81704f4594a4e202f3ace86a",
  "SR_No": "15",
  "Sheet_Name": "INFLUNCER LIST",
  "Review": "Influncer For collabration",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "In Progress",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "6020b21a81704f4594a4e202f3ace86a,16"
  },
  { 
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "e8ba4036b6b64db3abadce4741869f74",
  "SR_No": "16",
  "Sheet_Name": "IMAGE SIZE RATIO",
  "Review": "Image size ratios of all platforms",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "Completed",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "e8ba4036b6b64db3abadce4741869f74,17"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "a8410b59a15646679fda20054572564d",
  "SR_No": "17",
  "Sheet_Name": "SOCIAL MEDIA PLATFORM",
  "Review": "All social media platform usernames, passwords \n 
  and links.",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "In Progress",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "a8410b59a15646679fda20054572564d,18"
  },
  { 
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "30cd389cf38a4e2b8cc050cec1d64898",
  "SR_No": "18",
  "Sheet_Name": "DAILY POSTING DATA",
  "Review": "Data of all posted blogs .",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "In Progress",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "30cd389cf38a4e2b8cc050cec1d64898,19"
  },
  {
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "a81f212f5b41489cb1a2e0004baf4215",
  "SR_No": "19",
  "Sheet_Name": "OVERSEAS POSITION",
  "Review": "Data of Overseas Positions",
  "Ms_Shruti_Review": "In Progress",
  "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
  "__PowerAppsId__": "a81f212f5b41489cb1a2e0004baf4215,20"
  }
  ],
  "@odata.nextLink": "https://india-001.azure- 

apim.net/apim/googlesheet/0f06f26272de40baa02f8945bc5625f5/datasets/
1nySnd4-PKJfSIoOnXe31D_M-wiZeIlKWPVOTW8NUxmg/tables/495289366/items? %24skip=256"
}
 Output Of Filter Action in PowerAutomate:
 [
 {
 "@odata.etag": "",
 "ItemInternalId": "61a29650d840475b877250f1dbc0c561",
 "SR_No": "1",
 "Sheet_Name": "PROVIDED SERVICES TO INDUSTRY",
 "Review": "Similar Webite To Beneficiation",
 "Ms_Shruti_Review": "In Progress",
 "Mr_Girish_Review": "In Progress",
 "__PowerAppsId__": "61a29650d840475b877250f1dbc0c561,2"
 }
 ]


Could you share what you have in Get Rows and Filter Array, expand and share screenshots.

Do you see correct values in your textInput1_1Value, textInput1_2Value and textInput1_3Value variables? Also, you are using standard "Respond to Power App" action in the flow, which returns the output in text/string format (not as a "object") AND finally, you cannot set value of text inputs in power apps using formulas like "TextInput1_1.Text = textInput1_1Value". You will have to set "Default" property of text input control to respective variables instead. Let me know if you need any further help regarding this.

@AlmasMahfooz  I've added the output of the get and filter action in my question above

Im getting the correct values in textInput1_1Value,textInput1_2Value,textInput1_3Value.
@GaneshSanap-MVP. I tried setting the default property but it isn't working.
